# How to select a value given a set of criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following table and would like to select the $
for products when index = max:

```
id     product     $      max?
1         A        1       No
2         B        2       No
3         A        2       No
4         C        4       No
5         D        5       No
6         A        3       Yes
7         B        6       Yes
8         C        8       Yes
```

How do I get the results in the column identified max?

Regards.

Comment: Do you need formula for `max` column?

Comment: id=5, max? should be "Yes". Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD:**

> The results should be based on the max id and not max $. I am sorry for the confusion

If you need formula for `max` column based on max id, try next one:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(B:B=B2,A:A))=A2,"Yes","No")
```

where `B:B` column with your products, `A:A` - column with id.

Just select `D2`, enter formula in formula bar, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag it down.

Note, if you know exact ranges of your data, you can change `B:B` and `A:A` to e.g. `$B$2:$B$100` and `$A$2:$A$100`

Comment: The results should be based on the max id and not max $. I am sorry for the confusion. I think if C is replaced with A it should work i.e. =IF(MAX(IF(B:B=B2,A:A))=C2,"Yes","No") ?

Comment: not quite so, you should also change `C2` to `A2`, next formula should work: `=IF(MAX(IF(B:B=B2,A:A))=A2,"Yes","No")`. See my updated answer